# Muliple Services producing same eventType and publishing to same kafka topic

Tags: design-patterns, apache-kafka, publish-subscribe

I have a situation where I have an inventory being handled by multiple microservices based on the inventory type. The message type is similar to all these inventories with optional paramaters in the message that is specific to that particular inventory. I want these services to publish to the same topic so that, we have one topic our subscribers need to listen to and also hide the fact that there are multiple micro services handling the inventory from rest of the system.
This becomes a scenario of many to many, where we have multiple producers and multiple consumers.

Is this a good design. What are the pros and cons of this approach?

Currently I am splitting up into multiple topics and making the consumers to subscribe to each of those topics.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka alone doesn't care about the format of messages. You could look into the CloudEvents event format to create a "envelope event" that includes the type, prior to deserializing what you need.

The cons of one topic include more narrow failure scope (one topic has a higher percentage of failure, rather than multiple), and your consumer code could be more complex. With small partition sizes, it's also possible to experience delay in processing less common types, due to the fact that other events would saturate the topic.

The downside of multiple topics is that, unless you use some consistent regex pattern for those topic names to which the consumer subscribes, you'll need to redeploy your consumer with new configs.